# How to evaluate these improper integrals (if they’re even possible)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

I’m trying to evaluate the following two integrals: $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}\cos(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
and
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{x^2}\cos(x)}{1+x^2}dx.$$

The first one I know is convergent (from wolframalpha) but I cannot calculate its value.

The second one i suspect to be divergent since the integrand oscillates a lot, but maybe you can find some sort of symmetry in it where things cancel out each other.

I’ve tried looking at some complex contour integrals along for example a semicircle closed by the real axis to be able to make use of the residue theorem, but I always end up with the integral being divergent on some part of the curve. I think a different approach is needed.

Comment: How about expressing cos(x) in terms of e^(îx)+e^(-ix) and then evaluating the resulting infinite series integral?

Comment: According to a calculator, the first integral should be 1.146604500880079, while the second integral appears to be divergent.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try evaluating it as an infinite series. If possible I would like to end up with a closed form for the answer though, ideally without any sums or integrals left over.

Answer (score 1):

Reference... Item 3.945.2 in G&R:

*Gradshteyn, I. S.; Ryzhik, I. M.; Zwillinger, Daniel (ed.); Moll, Victor (ed.)*, [**Table of integrals, series, and products. Translated from the Russian. Translation edited and with a preface by Victor Moll and Daniel Zwillinger**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123849335), Amsterdam: Elsevier/Academic Press (ISBN 978-0-12-384933-5/hbk; 978-0-12-384934-2/ebook). xlv, 1133 p. (2015). [ZBL1300.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1300.65001).

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\beta x^2}\cos (ax)}{x^2+\gamma^2}\;dx 
\\ &=
\frac{\pi e^{\beta\gamma^2}}{4\gamma}\left[2\cosh(a\gamma)+
e^{-a\gamma}\Phi\left(-\gamma\sqrt{\beta}+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\beta}}\right)
-e^{a\gamma}\Phi\left(\gamma\sqrt{\beta}+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\beta}}\right)
\right],
\\
&\qquad \text{Re }\beta > 0, \text{Re }\gamma > 0, a > 0 .
\end{align}
Note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty = 2 \int_0^\infty$; plug in $\beta=1, \gamma=1, a=1$; recall the notation $\Phi = \text{erf}$.  We then get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}\cos x}{x^2+1}\;dx =
-\frac{\pi}{2}\, \left( {{\rm e}^{2}}{\rm erf} \left(3/2\right)-{{\rm e}^{2
}}+{\rm erf} \left(1/2\right)-1 \right) 
$$

Comment: I suspect this can be achieved by developing $\cos(x)$ in power series (taking care of the permutation of limits). I think this leads to $erf$, but I wasn't able to simplify the mess.

Comment: Thank you! You wouldn’t happen to know how to derive that formula?